# Find a countable set that contains pi and is closed under addition and multiplication

Tags: galois-theory

I need to find a set A, subset of R (reals) which has the following properties:
1. A is countable
2. A is closed under addition(+) and multiplication(*)
3. pi belongs to A
4. to every polynomial P with coefficients in A, the roots of P is also in A

Comment: So, what is stopping you?

Comment: 4, I tried all the sums of elements of the following set: { pi^r * a | a is algebraic, r is rational}
but I don't know how to prove 4.

Comment: I don't think it's true for that set. The roots of $x^5-\pi x-\pi$ presumably can't be expressed in radicals, even allowing $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For any set $S$ let $[S]^{<\omega}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $S$. Let $\varphi:[\Bbb R]^{<\omega}\to[\Bbb R]^{<\omega}$. Say that a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is *closed under* $\varphi$ if $\varphi(F)\subseteq A$ for each $F\in[A]^{<\omega}$. Define

$$\Phi:\wp(\Bbb R)\to\wp(\Bbb R):A\mapsto A\cup\left\{\varphi(F):F\in[A]^{<\omega}\right\}\;.$$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ and $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ let

$$\Phi^n(A)=\begin{cases}
A,&\text{if }n=0\\
\Phi\big(\Phi^{n-1}(A)\big),&\text{if }n>0\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let $$\overline{\Phi}(A)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Phi^n(A)\;.$$

- Show that if $A$ is countable, so is $\overline{\Phi}(A)$.
- Show that $\overline{\Phi}(A)$ is closed under $\varphi$.
- Figure out how this applies to your problem.

This is a useful technique that can be generalized considerably.